# Access to class data from handler for boost deadline_timer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was able to create a handler for a boost deadline_time (which is a member)
by declaring it static. Unfortunately this prevents the access to non-static member data.

I have a series of timeouts. So my idea was to have a single deadline_timer
while maintaining an ordered list of timeout events.
Every time the next timeout event would happen,
the class would retrigger the timer with the next timeout event in the class
calculating the remaining time for this timeout event.

For this concept to work the handler would need to manipulate
non-static data. But this is not possible sence boost::asio requires a static handler.

Anybody got an idea how to handle this?

```
class TimerController {
public:
void setTimer(const eibaddr_t gad, const timesecs_t timedelay);  
void cancelTimer(const eibaddr_t gad);
bool isRunning(const eibaddr_t gad);
void setGad(const eibaddr_t gad);
static void timerHandler(const boost::system::error_code &ec); 
private:
boost::asio::deadline_timer* m_pTimer;
struct timerList_s
{
    eibaddr_t gad;
    boost::posix_time::ptime absTimeOut;
    timerList_s(const timerList_s& elem) : gad(elem.gad),
                                           absTimeOut(elem.absTimeOut)
    {
    };
    timerList_s(const eibaddr_t& pgad, const boost::posix_time::ptime pato) 
        : gad(pgad),
          absTimeOut(pato)
    {
    };
    timerList_s& operator= (const timerList_s& elem)
    {
        gad = elem.gad;
        absTimeOut = elem.absTimeOut;
        return *this;
    };
    bool operator< (const timerList_s& elem) const
    {
        return (absTimeOut < elem.absTimeOut);
    };
    bool operator== (const timerList_s& elem) const
    {
        return (gad == elem.gad);
    };
};
std::list<timerList_s> m_timers;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the `deadline_timer` class with non-static data using `boost::bind` in the following way `deadline_.async_wait(bind(&client::check_deadline, this));`. Details available in ASIO's examples, for instance, [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This showed me how to solve the problem. As I want to discriminate between a cancelled and an expired timer i need to pass the error code (see the argument of my handler above). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918911/better-boost-asio-deadline-timer-example for a discussion of this topic. So I need to pass the argument using m_pTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(&TimerController::timerHandler, this, _1)). See the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426802/boost-asio-async-wait-handler

Answer (score 0):

> I have a series of timeouts. So my idea was to have a single
>   deadline_timer while maintaining an ordered list of timeout events.
>   Every time the next timeout event would happen, the class would
>   retrigger the timer with the next timeout event in the class
>   calculating the remaining time for this timeout event.

this is a very odd design.

> For this concept to work the handler would need to manipulate
>   non-static data. But this is not possible sence boost::asio requires a
>   static handler.

boost::asio does not require a static handler, see the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html). It requires a [handler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html) with the [signature](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WaitHandler.html)

```
void handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& error // Result of operation.
);
```

The typical recipe here is to use `boost::bind` to bind a member function to the handler. The [async TCP client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp) shows one way to do this. The author of the asio library has an [excellent blog post](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/bind-illustrated.html) describing this concept in detail if you have trouble understanding it.

Comment: Hi Sam, can you please explain, why you think this design is odd.

Comment: @Michael the rest of my answer explains why your design is odd, you assumed the handler needs to be static when that is not the case.